# Does Black Hole mass increase widen gravitational radius?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, mass, event-horizon

This is a question about the gravitational radius of SMBH's

As far as I know if our Sun collapsed to a BH it would still hold most of the present solar system together

Some matter would be lost via supernova but this would only decrease the gravitational radius and a few planets might be lost

If another BH (of equal mass) plowed into the Sun-BH and they merged would this then increase the gravitational radius of the merged object?

Would the gravitational radius double so our Solar System radius would be twice as large? (New outer planets could be captured...)

As far as I know a BH (basically) retains the gravitational radius of it's progenitor star

In the case that it's only the Event Horizon which increases and not the overall reaching hold of gravity I am baffled because what type of star would be large enough to collapse to a galaxy holding AGN?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius

Comment: In order to make your question intelligible to more people, I suggest avoiding acronyms like SMBH and AGN.

Comment: *a BH (basically) retains the gravitational radius of it's progenitor star* Not if it “swallows” more matter or radiation.

Answer (score 0):

Every object has an infinite gravitational radius. Two equal mass black holes merging would increase the gravity strength but the radius is already as big as it can be.